# The pass cannot be read because it isn't valid

Tags: ios6, passbook

I am following Apple's pdf to create pkpass manually, I have created a folder put icon.png, icon@2x.png, logo.png etc. I put pass.json file and also manifest.json. I double check that SHA1 is right for each file. I signed it as per doc. but it gives me "The pass cannot be read because it isn't valid." When I try to present via view controller. here it is

```
 PKPass *pass = [[PKPass alloc]  initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:passPath] error:&err];
 PKAddPassesViewController *vc = [[PKAddPassesViewController alloc] initWithPass:pass];
 [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];**
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok Seems I got the resolution, not sure why it is not working even if it is from Apple doc.
the problem line is

```
zip -r example.pass path/to/pass_package/* -x '*.DS_Store'
```

What I did instead, is following

```
cd pass_package
zip -r ../example.pass .
```

And it worked, now example.pass works well.

Comment: This now works because the pass content is now in the root of the zip file.  Previously, it would have failed because the zip would have included your path.

Comment: ``zip -r -j ...`` would remove the path from files as well